# Windows Task Scheduler not running task despite trigger

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

please keep in mind throughout this that I am quite new to windows automation and powerShell so go easy on me please. My goal was to create an automatic USB cloner in order to copy files if the drive has a specific name. I've sorted the copying and the name thing in powerShell and batch. Now remember the goal is to have the script running 24/7, based on a lot of reading up on this it would seem that Windows Task Scheduler is the Ideal way to do this. So I set up a task where the action is running the powerShell and the trigger is "At log on of any user" (I am the only user anyway). This is all well and good however when I log off and back in to test it, It doesn't work. I investigated and it turns out in Task Scheduler, for the usbClone task the status says "Ready" as opposed to "Running" (which is what it should be). Also I have ticked the "Enabled" button on the trigger. For reference my OS is Windows 10. If there is a flaw in my logic (I wouldn't be surprised) please explain, other than that it should be a simple "run this script on log on" task yet it isn't working. I should also point out that if I manually right click the task and click "Run" it runs just fine. Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT: Please read comments to see what steps I have already taken based on suggestion.

Thanks in advance,
Fane

Comment: here are the things to look at,
in General, Tab tick Run whether the user logged in or not, it will ask you credentials and let it save it and try again.
Second, you want that script to run 24/7 so change the trigger to repeat every second or write logic to repeat in your script once it starts executing or triggered.

Comment: Yeah I already had the setting for whether logged in or not, and with regards to the scheduled thing, even with it running as often as possible (every 1 minute), it still wouldn't run and just sit as "Ready"

Comment: check you and set correct windows environment and in condition tab remove check from "run when on AC power" as you might be running your machine on batteries.you can also tick run schedule sooner if misses schedule time just to be safe else you script might have problem

Comment: I tried all of the above and none of it seems to have changed the status. I'm beginning to think this may be more than a simple trigger issue...